# Inplace swap logic doesn't work in Quick sort but swapping using temp variable works. Why?

Tags: java, quicksort, swap

In the quick sort implemented below, I am taking the first element of the array as pivot. The sort algorithm works perfectly fine when I swap the elements using temp variable but it doesn't work (adds 0s as elements in the sorted array) when I swap them inplace. Kindy explain what is the problem in this code.

```
    public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int start, int end)
    {
        if(start < end)
        {
            int partition = partition(arr, start, end);

            quickSort(arr, start, partition-1);
            quickSort(arr, partition+1, end);
        }
    }

    public static Integer partition(int[] arr, int start, int end)
    {

        int pivot = start, i = start, j = end;

        while(i<j)
        {
            while(i<end && arr[i]<=arr[pivot])
            {
                i++;
            }

            while(arr[j]>arr[pivot])
            {
                j--;
            }

            if(i<j)
            {
                arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i] - arr[j];
                arr[i] = arr[i] - arr[j];   //It doesn't work

               /*int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;     
                */                          //It works


            }
        }
        arr[pivot] = arr[pivot] + arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[pivot] - arr[j];
        arr[pivot] = arr[pivot] - arr[j];   //It doesn't work

        /*int temp = arr[pivot];
        arr[pivot] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;     
        */                          //It works
        return j;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: One problem is the "not working" form is too tricky for its own good.  The temp variable code is obviously correct. I had to resort to pencil and paper to see what the in-place swap was attempting. Since the in-place swap is unclear, probably less efficient, and might have overflow problems, I'd reject it in code review.  Having said that, I don't immediately see its error.

Comment: Overflow, at least, is not a problem; `+` and `-` are inverse operations even when overflow occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between this "in-place swap" algorithm and the "out-of-place swap" algorithm is that the latter works when `pivot` and `j` are the same index, but the former does not.

This is what your code looks like if we imagine the two indices are the same:

```java
        arr[j] = arr[j] + arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j] - arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j] - arr[j];
```

The second line always sets `arr[j]` to 0, irrespective of its original value, and the third line leaves it as 0. If you absolutely must do without the extra local variable, then you will need to guard the swap with `if(j != pivot) { ... }`. But this probably makes it slower due to the extra comparison, conditional jump, and the potential for [branch prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) misses.

Comment: Normally for Hoare partition scheme, the pivot is not swapped into place, so those 3 lines don't need to be there, but then the 2 recursive calls should be | quickSort(arr, start, partition); | quickSort(arr, partition+1, end); |